# What qmake variable to set, to disable Visual Studio 2010's warning LNK4075

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qmake

Our windows builds generate hundreds of warnings of this form:

```
LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/FORCE' specification
```

I would like to disable this warning, at least temporarily, to make it easier to spot and resolve other warnings.

I've seen [Visual C++: How to disable specific linker warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661606/104370) which suggests that I should be able to set `/ignore:4075`, but am unsure which qmake variable should I add that to?

I've looked at the variables in the [qmake Variable Reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-lflags), and there are plenty of LFLAGS-related options, and without a large amount of trial and error, I'm unsure which to use.

So, what qmake variable should I adjust, with what value, to turn off `LNK4075`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which of the LFLAGS you use depends on what you are building.

- Windows Console (no GUI) App => QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE
- Windows Console (no GUI) DLL => QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE_DLL
- Windows GUI app => QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS
- Windows GUI DLL => QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS_DLL

To use them, just add the flag you need to the appropriate one.

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_xyzzy += /ignore:4075
```

If you are really in doubt, add it to all of them.

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding ` /ignore:4075` to all 4 of those variables, as suggested. It did add that option to the .vcxproj file, but sadly Visual Studio still generates the `LNK4075` warnings. I guess that means there's no way to disable that warning any more. Thanks anyway.